# Very random behaviour in Node with gm, buffers and promises

Tags: node.js, buffer, q, graphicsmagick

I recently switched my image saving module over to `gm` (grahicsmagick) and began using buffers instead of saving to disk.

The output I expect is an array with an md5 hash, then the paths to the original image and the thumbnail. I use promises, like this.

```
saveOrig( imageUrl )
.then( saveThumb )
.then( function( image ) {
    var returnArray = [ image.hash, image.orig, image.thumb ]
    console.log( returnArray )
    resolve( returnArray )
})
.catch( function( error ) {
    reject( new Error( error.message ) )
})
```

Here is the first function, the next one is almost identical

```
function saveOrig ( imageUrl ) {
    return Q.Promise( function ( resolve, reject, notify ) {

        var image = {
            extension: path.extname( imageUrl )
        }

        gm( request( imageUrl ) )
            .format( function( err, value ) {
                if ( err ) return reject ( new Error ( err ) )

                image.type = value
            })
            .stream( image.type, function ( err, stdout, stderr ) {
                if ( err ) return reject( new Error( err ) )

                var bufs = []

                stdout.on( 'data', function ( d ) {
                    bufs.push( d )
                })

                stdout.on( 'end', function () {
                    var buf = Buffer.concat( bufs )

                    image.hash = crypto.createHash( 'md5' ).update( buf ).digest( 'hex' )

                    console.log ( image.hash )

                    uploader = s3Client.putBuffer( buf, type + "/" + image.hash + "-orig" + image.extension, {
                        'Content-Length': buf.length,
                        'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
                    }, function ( err, result ) {
                        if ( err ) return reject( new Error( err ) )

                        if ( result.statusCode == 200 ) {
                            image.orig = uploader.url

                            resolve( image )
                        }
                    })
                })
            })
    })
}
```

Again, here's what I expect to see,

```
[ '820f841a0a7cdc854b70f8b534dc7705',
'https://my-amazon-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/read/820f841a0a7cdc854b70f8b534dc7705-orig.jpeg',
'https://my-amazon-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/read/820f841a0a7cdc854b70f8b534dc7705-thumb.jpeg' ]
```

That's what happens when I process just one image. But when I call this function mapped to an array with `Q.all`, I get extremely random seeming mixtures of hashes, thumbnails and original paths, presumably from other calls to the function before it.

I didn't have this behaviour before when I wasn't using buffers or `gm`. What's the cause of this?

---

Edit: here's how I call the `saveImage` function described above. This seemed to work fine when I was saving items to disk, then manipulating them with the easy-image module.

```
images = window.document.getElementsByTagName( 'img' )

imageMapFunction = Array.prototype.map.call( images, function ( each, index ) {
    return Q.promise( function ( resolve, reject, notify ) {


    saveImage( req.body.type, each.src )
    .spread( function ( imageHash, imageOriginalPath, imageThumbPath ) {
        article.images.push({
            image: imageOriginalPath,
            imageHash: imageHash,
            imageThumb: imageThumbPath
        })

        each.src = imageOriginalPath

        resolve()
    })

    })
})

Q.all( imageMapFunction )
.then( function () {
```

Comment: Possible: `uploader = s3Client.putBuffer` => `var uploader = s3Client.putBuffer`. Whenever you have something where different calls start polluting eachother, missings `var` statements are the first thing to look for. You also use `type` instead of `image.type` so I'm not sure why that function is working.

Comment: I will try this, thanks. `type` is declared somewhere else.

Comment: Okie doke, that works. If type is a global, I'd hope that it's a constant of some kind, in which case making it ALL_CAPS would be recommended.

Comment: @loganfsmyth please submit this as an answer so I can give you proper credit.

Comment: WIll do, was just waiting to hear that it had solved it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section is incorrect:

```
uploader = s3Client.putBuffer( buf, type + "/" + image.hash + "-orig" + image.extension, {
    'Content-Length': buf.length,
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
}, function ( err, result ) {
    if ( err ) return reject( new Error( err ) )

    if ( result.statusCode == 200 ) {
        image.orig = uploader.url

        resolve( image )
    }
});
```

You need a `var` in there as `var uploader`.

As it is now, if you call your function multiple times, you will overwrite a global `uploader` every time, so the final results you get back will depend on how long each image takes to process and how long they take to upload.

Answer (score 1):

Console.log is async; so it will spit things out in async order and so it can easily be out of order depending on what is currently logging.

If you really must track it via the console; use console.error as it is synchronous; or use a simple array to push everything into; and then log out that array at the very end.

Comment: I see the same output in the database where it gets passed. Plus it's within a promise so at worst I'd think it would say undefined, not data that it shouldn't know about at all.

Comment: BTW, usually this kind of thing goes in the "comments" ( see just under my question where it says "add a comment"), and just answers go here. Unless you think this is really the root of the problem.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me.  You can "basically" do a console.log("a") and then a console.log("b") in that order; and get out "b" then "a".   All depending on what is going on in the system; the busier the system the more likely you are to see some out-of-order console.logs.     So what I was stating was the data is resolved and present, but is getting output in the wrong order.        (However, I see that the real root of your issue was the missing "var")